# Trigger Dataflow job on file arrival in GCS using Cloud Composer

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm new to GCP and trying to gain a better understanding of ETL services offered by Google Cloud. I'm trying to do a POC where a dataflow job runs whenever a file arrives at a specified location in GCS, I want to utilize Cloud Composer for the same.

How can I utilize different airflow operators (one to watch for file in GCS and other to trigger dataflow job) in a DAG?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Cloud Function triggered when a file is created / arrives at your bucket. You can find how to deploy such function in the following documentation  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#deploy
2. Code your function to trigger your DAG, it's well explained in the following documentation: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf
3. Use one of the following airflow operators to run a dataflow job as a task within your DAG

- `DataflowCreateJavaJobOperator` if you are using Java SDK
- `DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator` if you are using Python SDK

More details here : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/2.1.0/operators/cloud/dataflow.html

---

That was the answer to your question about composer, but **you should consider replacing Composer by [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/quickstart-console)**, and rather than using an airflow  dataflow operator, you can use [Cloud Workflows dataflow connector](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/dataflow/Overview), and you can code your cloud function to trigger a Cloud Workflows execution. There are many clients library in different languages to do that. Here the link to choose your library: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/libraries

Finally Cloud Workflows pros compared to Composer.

- it's serverless: you don't have to bother about machine types, network, ...
- you use yaml to describe your workflow in easy and fast way, so you don't have to worry about learning airflow
- it's way cheaper than composer
- ...

Comment: Hi Phoenix, thanks for your response, I'll definitely try this out as well, but mainly what I was looking for was how i can configure two different airflow operators, one would be a sensor for file upload on gcs and other to trigger the java dataflow job, I'm having trouble understanding how these two operators can be linked together so that dataflow operator executes the dataflow job whenever the file sensor operator finds a new file has been uploaded

Comment: IMHO, the solution I described will help you get rid of the sensor. Such sensor will use pplling every n seconds but the the triggered Cloud Function is more reactive and will trigger your dag ASAP the file is added to your bucket.

Comment: Okay, got it. Will test this out